# how to show my url images in full screen?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

i created one grid view application, it's working fine now showing all images in grid view. now i am trying to display selected image in full screen, but i am getting error. my grid view images are downloaded in url link. my url link are stored in array list. how to solve this error? 
error class name is FullImageActivity.class

error: `imageAdapter1.GridViewConfig cannot be resolved or is not a field`

error line :

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter1.GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position));
```

this is my coding:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter1 = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter1.GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position));
    }

}
```

ImageAdapter.class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {


    private Context context;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        //Listeye image url si ekliyor
        GridViewConfig.addImageUrls();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GridViewConfig.getResim_list().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            imageView=new ImageView(context.getApplicationContext());
            //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        }else{
            imageView=(ImageView)convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position)));
        return imageView;
    }

//Internetten imageleri stream olarak  cekip drawable olsurturuyor.
    private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url)
    {
    try
    {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
    return d;
    }catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    return null;
    }
    }

}
```

GridViewconfig.class

```
public class GridViewConfig {
    private static ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int[] getResim_list;

    public static ArrayList<String> getResim_list() {
        return resim_list;
    }

    public static void setResim_list(ArrayList<String> resim_list) {
        GridViewConfig.resim_list = resim_list;
    }

    public static void addImageUrls(){
        resim_list.add("http://igen.com/Images/Home/Client-Logo.png");


    }
}
```

MyGridView.class

```
public class MyGridView extends Activity {
    private GridView girGridView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        girGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1_bir);
//ListView gibi buna da adapter set ediliyor.
        girGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

        girGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {

                  // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
    }
        });
    }
}
```

I posted my full source code.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: GridViewConfig indeed is not a field of your ImageAdapter.

Second:
`imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter1.GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position));`

it will not work: getResim_list() returns ArrayList, it contains String values NOT int

You can try change :

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

       // get intent data
       Intent i = getIntent();

       // Selected image id
       int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
       GridViewConfig.addImageUrls();
       imageView.setImageDravable(LoadImageFromURL(GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position)));
    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url) {
        ....
    }

}
```

But in my opinion you should rewrite all your code. The main problem: the drawings must be loaded in a separate thread.